# How to connect airflow with database by unsing Astronomer

Tags: airflow, astronomer

Please tell me how I can connect Apache Airflow (I run it via “astro” on the local computer) and my database (PostgreSQL), which is also installed on my local computer?

Traceback

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

By the way, how can I enable connection testing in the admin-connection panel? (I tried to write test_connection = Enabled in the airflow.cfg file inside the docker container, but it does not work, even after rebooting the container)

I tried adding "host.docker.localhost" to the connection, but it didn't help.

Comment: If you're an Astronomer customer, please raise a support ticket.

Comment: Are you attempting to access the Airflow database that's created when running `astro dev start`? Or are you trying to connect to a separate Postgres database that's also running locally, in addition to the Airflow database?

Comment: @RNHTTR I want to access a separate database. I will not work with a database in a container. So I need to connect to my database.

Comment: I think you want the Connection object to reference `host.docker.internal` and not `host.docker.localhost`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24326540/7004653)